# Backbone marionette new architecture and cdnJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to use CDNJS as my marionette repository.

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/1.0.0-rc2/backbone.marionette.min.js

However I'm getting dependecies error:

[image: screenshot of console]

I realize the project was split into several parts so I tried adding the other projects:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter/master/lib/backbone.babysitter.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.wreqr/0.1.0/backbone.wreqr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/1.0.0-rc2/backbone.marionette.min.js"></script>
```

with no effect.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added the bundled version to cdnjs: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/1.0.0-rc4-bundled/backbone.marionette.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Just use the bundled version which has all the needed dependency in one single file: http://marionettejs.com/#download

Comment: do you know of a CDN repository that hosts the bundled version?